# Unexpected non-void return value in void function in Swift using numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question has already been asked numerous times, but nothing seems to be working in my particular case. As you can see in my code below, I have created an extension of my View Controller for my UITableViewDataSource. I am trying to pull information from my Firebase Realtime Database and depending on what I get, return a certain Int. The issue is that whenever I try and return an Int from within the Firebase Snapshot, I receive this error: "Unexpected non-void return value in void function." I understand the reason for this, but I am not sure how I can make my code work. Any solutions?

My code:

```
extension LikeOrDislikeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let uid  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        Database.database().reference().child("Num Liked").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let numMoviesLiked = ((dictionary["Number of Movies Liked"] as? Int))!

                if numMoviesLiked%4 == 0 {
                    return numMoviesLiked/4
                }
            }
        })
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        tableView.rowHeight = 113
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay a return call in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318806/how-to-delay-a-return-call-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this `return numRows`  inside the database block , it doesn't consider to return any values  , also the call is asynchronous so don't expect it to finish before the `return 10` of `numberOfRowsInSection`, completely remove this part and put it inside `viewDidLoad`

```
Database.database().reference().child("Num Liked").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let numMoviesLiked = ((dictionary["Number of Movies Liked"] as? Int))!

        if numMoviesLiked/4 == 0 {
            numRows = numMoviesLiked/4
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
```

---

logically if you do if only when you compare `numMoviesLiked/4 == 0` then `numRows` will be always 0

Comment: This no longer returns an error, but it does not do what I had intended. I think did something in my code that is confusing you. Also, thanks for the note at the bottom, I meant to use %. Anyway, I have edited my question so maybe it will make sense now in the context that I wanted.